# How to count the number of files in current directory that contain a specific phrase?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to count number of files in current directory that contain the phrase "HW".

I tried

```
ls -l | grep HW | wc -l
```

Comment: HW is a string inside the file, or in the filename?

Answer (score 0):

To count how many files have in it the string "HW", the following will do:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs grep -m 1 HW | wc -l
```

If your directory has only regular files:

```
grep -m 1 HW * 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

If you are looking for *filenames* that have the string "HW" in it:

```
find . -type f -name "*HW*" | wc -l
```

Comment: Is there any other way instead of using find ?

Comment: It there a problem in using `find`, or that is just for the sake of curiosity?

Comment: find doesn't work. it gives me a list of every file in the directory.

Comment: That is the idea, so you can pipe it to `grep`. You could use `grep -m 1 HW *` if your directory contains only regular files.